# I ran this command in terminal->npm install --save express-handlebars but still handlebars is not in my dependencies

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

created an app.js file and ran the npm install --save express-handlebars command. Do I need to run something else to have handlebars in my package.json dependencies ?

Comment: Have you initialised the project (`npm init`) first?

Comment: Yes, I ran the command npm init -y, and my package.json file is ready

Comment: Does the package show up if you run `npm list` in the directory?

Comment: yes, it does show

Comment: ok, got it, I ran the npm init command twice, was looking for express.json in the second package.json file

Comment: express file* in second json file

Answer (score 1):

[`express-handlebars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) has [`handlebars` listed as a dependency](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars/blob/2c93b7f38a4873dae7f4bcbae6a92b69db10700c/package.json#L29), so that will get [installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) into your **node_modules/** folder without it being added to your **package.json** file.

If you would like to install a different version of handlebars, you can do so via the normal flow:

```
npm install --save-exact handlebars@YOUR.VERSION.HERE
```

You can then [pass this version of handlebars into your `exphbs()` call](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars#handlebarsrequirehandlebars) to set the different version:

```js
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const expressHandlebarsInstance = exphbs({ handlebars });
```